# How to calculate the volume of objects in millimeter cube?

Tags: image-processing, geometry, image-segmentation

I have two methods for calculating the volume of objects in a millimeter cube; please tell me which of them is correct or any other method for volume calculation.

```
%first method
[xx,yy,zz]=size(bw);%dicom images with x=320,y=270,z=28
mmm = voxel_count*(xx*yy*zz);
```

or

```
%second method 
vol_liters = voxel_count*prod(voxel_size)/1e6;% calculating in liters 
mmm = vol_liters*1000000;%   1 liter = 1000000 mm3
```

Comment: I feel like this is the wrong place to ask this question as this site is aimed towards programming and not equations/math. 

Break down your code into readable equations and ask your question here http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Volume depends on the geometric shape (ie sphere : 4/3.π.r³)

if rectangle paralelepipede and sizes in milimeters yes, x * y * z gives you the volume mm3 (= mm * mm * mm)

Comment: i want to find the volume of tumors from the segmented Dicom images, tumor have irregular shapes of different sizes how to calculate volume of  objects with irregular shapes.